# Allow always checkbox in Java security dialog when jnlp location is unknown (since Java 8u121)

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

In Java 8 Update 121 they implemented a [bugfix](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8157337), which causes the security dialog to handle jnlp files from a unknown location differently.
As far as I understand this fix, the location of a jnlp file will now be determined via a hash of the file.
My problem is, that I have some dynamic content in my remote jnlp file. So the hash is different with each call and the security dialog pops up, no matter if I click on "Do not show again" or not.

[image: Security Warning]

What's the right way to avoid this behavior? Should I pass arguments dynamically to the jnlp file?

Comment: Why is your jnlp considered to be "from an unknown location"? Maybe you can make it come from the same location than the jar it's using?

Comment: It's because the jnlp is dynamically generated by a servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed in Java 8 Update 161.
You can now define secure arguments within your JNLP, which won't be used for the hash calculation.
Simply put the property

```
  <property name="jnlp.secure.argument.<argument-name>" value="true"/>
```

into your jnlp file. You can also use a wildcard, so that all arguments are marked secure

```
  <property name="jnlp.secure.argument.*" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I also had the problem. I solved it by modifying my JNLP as follows,

param1, param2, param3 are the same which are passed to my

My JnlpServlet is populating param1, param2, param3 at both places i.e: jnlp.href and application-desc.main-class

The Java Web Start will download the JNLP and then cross check the hash again the one again jnlp.href output. Both would match hence no popup would be shown.

Hope this helps.

And also the issue started with Update [112](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/8u112-bugfixes-3124974.html) not 121